# ADBannerView constraints not working so ad jumps around on the screen

Tags: xcode, constraints, iad, adbannerview

I added constraints to an adbannerview so that it is locked to the top of the screen. It is also constrained to be centered horizontally. The three small constraints at the bottom are just for spacing.

For some reason the ad jumps around on the screen when I run the code in iOS simulator and on iPhones. It appears at the top of the screen occasionally but also jumps to the bottom of the screen despite constraints. I need a way to make sure it stays at the top of the screen.

[image: http://imgur.com/0jhIrYj,bh38rGt#1]

This is an example of the ad in iOS Simulator.

[image: http://imgur.com/0jhIrYj,bh38rGt#0]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're using `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES` in addition to implementing your own `ADBannerView`. Using `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES` will automatically create an `ADBannerView` for you and display it on the bottom of your devices screen. Remove `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES`.

Also, it looks like you have not pinned the leading and trailing space of your `ADBannerView` to your `view`/`Superview`.